# Left Side Caption on Graphics

Tags: graphics, labels

I have an included graphic in my report generated with this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\begin{center}Class guessed by the program
\includegraphics[width=16cm]{images/confusion}\begin{turn}{90}\hspace{25mm}Actual class of input\end{turn}
\end{center}
\caption{Confusion Matrix for 26 Classes.}
\label{fig:confusion}
\end{figure}
```

This generates the following image:[image: Matrix]

However it looks a bit untidy. I'd like the Y axis caption to be on the same place but on the left side of the image. What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is only that you positioned the `turn` environment after `\includegraphics`. Thus I've sanitized your code a bit:

- made your code compilable (important)
- moved the turning part (important)
- replaced `turn` by `\rotatebox` (unimportant, this makes the code not require `rotating`)
- added indentation (unimportant)

Output (I do not have the picture):

[image: blackbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
    Class guessed by the program
    \rotatebox{90}{\hspace{25mm}Actual class of input}\includegraphics[width=16cm]{images/confusion}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix for 26 Classes.}
    \label{fig:confusion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```